# What is difference between "extended Email notification" and "Email notification" in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to configure pipeline having email to be sent about pipeline status. For that I came across two mail configurations. [image]

and other one is--
[image]

I didn't able to find difference between these two configurations.

Answer (score 10):

They are two different plugins.

- **E-mail Notification** is from the plugin [Mailer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mailer) and allows to send a basic email.
- **Extended E-mail Notification** is from the plugin [Email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) and allows more customization, e.g. from the [plugin's page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin): "*when an email is sent, who should receive it, and what the email says*".  This plugin also allows to set default global parameters (e.g. recipient list) so you don't have to set these parameters on each and every project.

Comment: And as 2 different plugins, they are separate post-build options in your job.  Your screen shot is from the configuration page, so go ahead and configure them both.  Then you will see the difference once you start working with them.  The `Extended E-mail Notification` option is going to provide a greater ability to control your message based on the verdicts you determine in your job.